# Does display: none disable an <input>?

Tags: html, css, forms

I've experienced before the phenomenon that if an `<input>` tag has the CSS property `display: none`, then its value isn't submitted with its parent form. I'm now in the curious situation where that behaviour is helpful!

Can I rely on `display: none` to prevent inclusion of an input when its form is submitted, or is it technically a deviation from the spec?

**Edit:** The answers so far have all focussed on other ways of doing this, and the necessity of back-end validation, so let me be clear; I know this is a slightly odd way of doing things, and I know I need to validate on the back end. I already am; it's just that the format of the parameter I'm getting back makes one particular aspect of my processing slightly tricky.

As an attempt to rephrase the question slightly more clearly: **Is there a reliable in-CSS way to prevent an input from being included with its form?** It appears that setting a field's `display` to `none` *works*, but I haven't been able to tell whether it *should* work. I don't care about users potentially editing the front end HTML / CSS, because I will catch that on the back-end. You may assume a non-malicious user.

Comment: If you want to disable an input why not just use `<input type="input" disabled>`?

Comment: @DanielWilliams - This is easily overridden, i.e. if you have firebug simply deleting this attribute will enable the input (one of zillions of ways). NEVER, EVER TRUST USER INPUT, make sure that input is disabled in the backend too.

Comment: Why do I want to do this? I have a 2d radio button array - only one can be selected, but which one governs two conceptually different values. I'm currently using the values concatenated as the radio input value; but I was thinking about using the checkbox hack to selectively `display: none` a pair of hidden inputs instead.

Comment: @dwhite.me - don't worry, it's all validated on the back-end too :)

Comment: @dwhite.me that's not a great argument.. because if a user was opening firebug to remove that `disabled` they could just as easily untick the checkbox next to `display:none`... adding `disabled` is the cross-browser standards for disabling input.

Comment: @dwhite.me but display property is easily overridden too, anyone that have knowlodge of JS can override any js validation. To disable an input the ideal method is to use the disabled attribute. To UI you can use JS to disable the fields and apply the CSS or Animations dynamic while filling the form.

Comment: All I said, albeit long windedly, is any way of disabling in the frontend is easily tampered with even with the smallest level of experience. Validation will need to be reflected in back-end whichever way it is disabled and as the OP said this is already covered, we need not discuss this further!

Answer (score 5):

No. You should definitely use the `disabled` attribute.

With HTML5, some browsers(i.e. Chrome) will even prevent you from submitting the form when a required field was set to `display:none`

Comment: `disabled` would be nice, but I want to selectively enable/disable the fields based on whether a radio button is selected, and I'm trying to avoid a JS solution (as a point of progressive enhancement). I can't set `disabled` from CSS.

Comment: CSS is not meant to change behavior of an element but only *style*.
JS is how you change behavior

Answer (score 0):

If the radio buttons represent two sets of complex values, it sounds like you are doing it right by storing that information as the radio button's value attribute.

That said, since you are already having the user pick a radio button which determines which hidden inputs are applicable, why can't you handle that in the validation code? You could check the value of the radio button first, and then take one action or another.

This would make it more difficult for someone to work their way around your code because the form wouldn't change based on user interaction, only the items processed would. Someone couldn't make a enable a disabled hidden form element because there wouldn't be one, the ones that don't apply would just be ignored.

Comment: I can handle the value in the validation code. I currently do. But for various reasons, my life would be much easier if - assuming a non-evil user etc. etc. - I could expect to receive two separate values governed by the radios, instead of one single combined value.

Answer (score 0):

You can not rely on it as users can add values to that input, but if it's just to carry on some info, like to a second form and so on, just make sure to validate it in the backend always! You may wanna consider using php sessions :)

Comment: As I've already commented, and now edited in, I know that user can mess with the front end and that I need to back-end validate. I already do so. I'm trying to make my life easier in the case where the user isn't doing anything unusual.